# sql union remove "semi-duplicates"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm doing a union like so

```
select name, price from products where project = 10  // prio 1
union
select name, price from products where customer = 5  // prio 2
union
select name, price from products where standard = 9  // prio 3
```

**edit: changed the where-clause to make it a bit more complicated**

this will typically give me back

```
+-----+------+-----------+--------------+
|(NO) | name |  price    |  (prio)      |
+-----+------+-----------+--------------+
|  1  |  a   |    10     |  (1)         |
|  2  |  b   |     5     |  (1)         |

|  3  |  a   |    13     |  (2)         |
|  4  |  b   |     2     |  (2)         |

|  5  |  a   |     1     |  (3)         |
|  6  |  b   |     5     |  (3)         |
|  7  |  c   |     3     |  (3)         |
+-----+------+-----------+--------------+
```

I understand that e.g. row no 1 and 3 are not duplicates and will not be removed by the union statement. However, this is exactly what I want to do. That is, if a name (e.g. "a") gets returned by the first select statement (prio 1) I don't want any other "a":s to get into the result set from the select statements of higher priority.

i.e, I want this:

```
+-----+------+-----------+--------------+
|(NO) | name |  price    |  (prio) |
+-----+------+-----------+--------------+
|  1  |  a   |    10     |  (1)         |
|  2  |  b   |     5     |  (1)         |

|  7  |  c   |     3     |  (3)         |
+-----+------+-----------+--------------+
```

Is this possible?

I tried using `group by` but this requires me to use a MIN, MAX, AVG etc. on the price which I don't want to do, i.e:

```
select name, avg(price) from (...original query...) group by name
// this is not ok since I donnot want the avg price, I want the "first" price
```

I am using MS SQL 2000. Can I use something like `first(..)` as aggregate function in the `group by`? When trying this, I get an error:

```
select name, first(price) from (...original query...) group by name
// error: 'first' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Thanks!

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: @JW. I see you have a SQL Server answer ready to go. It is missing `WHERE  prio IN ( 1, 2, 3 )`

Comment: @MartinSmith but i think it won;t work in `SQL Server 2000` hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+:

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  name, price, prio,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name
                                ORDER BY prio ASC) rn
    FROM    products
)
SELECT  Name, Price
FROM    records
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Try this for `SQL Server 2000`:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    products a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  name, MIN(prio) min_prio
            FROM    products 
            WHERE   prio IN (1,2,3)
            GROUP   BY  name
        ) b ON a.name = b.name AND
                a.prio = b.min_prio
```

for better performance, add a compound index on column `(name, prio)`.

Comment: Thanks JW., this looks great! BUT, I'm sorry to have simplified the problem too much. If you are not to frustrated, take a look at the new where-clauses in the questing :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, price from products where prio = 1
union
select name, price from products where prio = 2 and name not in (select name from products where prio = 1)

union
select name, price from products where prio = 3 and name not in 
(select name from products where prio = 1
union
select name from products where prio = 2 and name not in (select name from products where prio = 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that works, but the idea is like this:

```
select name,
    min(case when prio=min_prio then price else NULL end) as price,
    min(prio) as min_prio
from products
group by name
order by min_prio
```